# Mutable Array of SimpleDB Items, Attributes and Values in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray

Below is this returned NSLog of an array (items3) of AWS SimpleDB Item with two attributes and two attribute values. I want to show a UITableView of the cell.textLabel.text = ItemName and cell.detailTextLabel.text = Value2.

```
items3 = (
    "ItemName",
        (
        "{Name: Attribute1,AlternateNameEncoding: (null),Value: Value1,AlternateValueEncoding: (null),<SimpleDBAttribute: 0x2eeaf0>}",
        "{Name: Attribute2,AlternateNameEncoding: (null),Value: Value2,AlternateValueEncoding: (null),<SimpleDBAttribute: 0x2f38e0>}",
    )
```

How do show all items, but only the value for Attribute2? Is there a way to say object for Key@"Attribute2" which equals value2?

Something like:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [itmes3 objectAtIndex: indexpath.row];
[[ cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[items3 objectAtIndex:0] stringForKey:@"Attribute2"];
```

Comment: Can I improve this question in some way? I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
for (SimpleDBItem *item in selectResponse.items)
```

then run a GetAttributesRequest on item.name, like this:

```
for (SimpleDBAttribute *attr in response.attributes) {
    if ([attr.name isEqualToString:@"Attribute2"])
```